# Failed to display data from the database in Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some tables here in the database which are **tickets** and **ticket_web_users**.

> The table **ticket_web_users** has **id**, **email** & **password** fields.

While the

> table **tickets** has **id**, **ticket_no**, and **web_user_id** fields.

and

> table **ticket_web_users**: **id**, **web_user_id** & **ticket_id**

Each ticket has many ticket web users. Here on my **show.html.erb**, I want to display the ticket information including the **web users** of a certain **ticket**. In short, I want to **display ALL of the web users of that ticket**. Here's my controller: **tickets_controller.rb**

```
module TicketManagement
 class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_ticket_web_user, only: [:show]

  def show
  end

  def get_ticket_web_user
   @web_ticket_users = TicketWebUser.where('ticket_id=?',params[:id])
  end
 end
end
```

**Models:**

**ticket.rb:**

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ticket_histories
  belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ticket_histories
end
```

**ticket_web_user.rb:**

```
class TicketWebUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :web_user
end
```

Here's my **view show.html.erb:**

```
  <% @web_ticket_users.each do |web_ticket_user| %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'web_user',value: web_ticket_user.email , class: 'form-control'%>
  <% end %>
```

It displaying an error: **NoMethodError in TicketManagement::Tickets#show,
undefined method `email' for TicketWebUser:0xb045bab8>**
I've searched some documents that can help me to fix my problem including [Ruby on Rails Guides on Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/active_record_querying.html) but I cannot find the method that has the same issue as mine.

Comment: Try to restart your server. And if ticket has a field `web_user_id` it can't `has_many :web_users', it `belongs_to :web_user`. You need to setup your models and associations properly and you can use in show action `@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])` and in view `@ticket.web_users`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you forget to add association on ticket_web_users

```
belongs_to :ticket
```

and another thing did you forget to add ticket_id on ticket_web_users table?

Can you provide code of the model ticket and ticket_web_user and column on ticket_web_users table?